# Add a 3rd tier to dropdown menu in CSS for Sharepoint 2010 Content Editor

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, menu

This code works as expected to produce a horizontal drop-down menu when plugged into a Content Editor web part in SharePoint 2010. I have had no end of trouble getting a third level of sub menu to work. I'm pretty new to CSS and HTML and I've tried a lot of methods on the Web but since I'm not really understanding what I am doing it is hard to make it work with the existing code. I just want one of the menu items to display a third sub menu directly to its right with the same colors when clicked/hovered as the other menus etc. Thanks for any assistance in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    
.navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #008080;
    color: white;
}

.navigation li {
    float: left;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: white;
}

.navigation li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white; !important
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.navigation li a:link, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: white;
}

.navigation li a:visited, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: white;
}

.navigation li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: White;
    color: black;
}

.navigation li.dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.navigation .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 115px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.navigation .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.navigation .dropdown-content a:link {color:#292929}
.navigation .dropdown-content a:visited {color: #292929}

.navigation .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #595959; color: white}
.navigation .dropdown-content a:active {color: white}

.navigation .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    background-color: #bddbdb;
color: white;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="navigation">
<ul>

<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn">Home</a>  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Home.png" width="30" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;I  I</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Home.png" width="30" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp; S RV</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn">MA</a>  <div class="dropdown-content">

  <a href="#"><img src="http://to/ts/Icons/011.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;S P</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://to/ts/Icons/1371.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;S S</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://to/ts/Icons/020.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;D I</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://to/ts/Icons/004.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;D P</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn">Files</a>  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Files.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;2020</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Files.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;2019</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Files.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;2018</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Files.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;2017</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Files.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;2016</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Files.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;2015</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn">O C</a>  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Ot147.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;OOC</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/O1222.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;PRS</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn">ans</a>  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/n.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;AN</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/PNQR122.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;I & M</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Plq.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;CP</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/Pn.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;RST</a>     
</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn">D L</a> <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/F.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;TD</a> 
</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn">RP</a> <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/E.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;CT</a> 
  <a href="#"><img src="http://sharepoint/GSites/Services/Shared%20documents/OP_Images/C.png" width="25" align="middle" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;S C</a>      
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS 3 Level Dropdown Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879786/css-3-level-dropdown-menu)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I attempted integrate this into my code but it did not show the sub menu. I think it is because my code is structured a bit differently in the CSS around drop-downs and hover etc.  So not sure what needs to happen to make this work. Also the menu item that should show the sub menu is only partially colored light blue when dropped down and the rest of the list to the right of that menu item is white just like the parent so not sure why that is either?

Comment: Did Lee_MSFT solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one（based on [this demo](http://tribodoci.net/artigos/menu-dropdown-css/)), add limit to not effect other SharePoint elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #MyNav ul {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            background: rgb(22, 160, 133);
        }

        #MyNav li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

            #MyNav li:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }

        #MyNav ul ul {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }

            #MyNav ul ul li {
                display: block;
            }

            #MyNav ul ul ul {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
            }
        /*************
        * EXTRA CSS
        *************/
        #MyNav a {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            #MyNav a:hover {
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="MyNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Php</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">SQL</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">PostgreSQL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MySql</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Redes Sociais</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Update:

Add more nodes for your reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #MyNav ul {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            background: rgb(22, 160, 133);
        }

        #MyNav li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

            #MyNav li:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }

        #MyNav ul ul {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }

            #MyNav ul ul li {
                display: block;
            }

            #MyNav ul ul ul {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
            }
        /*************
        * EXTRA CSS
        *************/
        #MyNav a {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            #MyNav a:hover {
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="MyNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Php</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">SQL</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">PostgreSQL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MySql</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Redes Sociais</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">ChildNode1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ChildNode2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Twitter1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Twitter2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that example works fine in its entirety but I am not understanding how to incorporate the third level menu code into my code? I've tried a lot of ways but just can't get it to work. Thanks for any suggestions..